# Python: Check is each value is between/equal to 0 to 3 in the tuple?

Tags: python, list, boolean, tuples

I need to change this in a way so that I can verify that every number is equal to 0 or less than or equal to 3.

```
def printPile(g):
    pile = g
    for i in range(len(pile)):
        a = (pile[0])
        b = (pile[1])
        c = (pile[2])
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
```

I am under the impression that this is how I should do it, is this okay?:

```
def isStablePile(g):
    pile = g
    for x in range(len(pile)):
        if 0<=x<=3:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
```

**isStablePile([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 0]]) will be the input for g**

Comment: You are looping

Comment: What is `g`, and what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: g is the tuple: ([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 0]])

Answer (score 0):

Your tabbing is off if you want to print each element only once.  Do this instead:

```
def printPile(g):
    pile = g
    for i in range(len(pile)):
        a = (pile[0])
        b = (pile[1])
        c = (pile[2])
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating stuff. All you need to do is this:

```
g = ('1','2','3')
print('\n'.join(g))
```

Or with a function and an example:

```
def printPile(g):
    print('\n'.join(g))

g = ('1','2','3')
printPile(g)
```

Returns

```
1
2
3
```

---

And how would I correct your example?

```
def printPile(g):
    for i in range(len(g)):
        print(g[i])
```

or:

```
def printPile(g):
    for i in g:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can make the program check for you if the values are in the correct range.

```
piles = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 0]]
are_piles_stable = all(0 <= pile <= 3 for pile in sum(piles, []))

print(are_piles_stable) # prints True
```

#### Explanation:

First, `sum(piles, [])` flattens `[[0, 1, 2], ...]` to `[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0]`.

Then, `all` checks that `0 <= pile <= 3` is `True` for all elements in the above list

You do not have to strive for short code like this. But it intends to show that you were overcomplicating a little bit. Also, why print all individual values to the screen and analyse them yourself when you can have the computer do it for you?